# SUBSTRING_INDEX with 2 delimiters

Tags: mysql, substring

I have 2 different types of item codes. It consist of 2 parts, `[companycode]-[itemcode]`. Below is the example:

A: `0888-DIA172966616`
B: `0888-PMA516998-2200000M`

I want to substring only the `[itemcode]` parts of it so I use

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(ItemCode, '-', -1)
```

It works fine with the A item code `DIA172966616`, but for the B, it gives me only the value from the second "-", so it's just `2200000M`. How to get the full item code for the B?

Comment: *How to get the full item code for the B?* Unclear. Does you need `'PMA516998-2200000M'` or `'PMA516998'`?

Comment: @Akina I need `PMA516998-2200000M` not only `PMA516998`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBTRING_INDEX()` is only useful if you want the first N or last N delimited strings, you can't use it directly for "all but first N".

Don't use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` for this, use `SUBSTR()` and `LOCATE()`

```
SUBSTR(ItemCode, LOCATE('-', ItemCode)+1)
```

`LOCATE(ItemCode, '-')` returns the position of the first `-`, and `SUBSTR()` then returns everything after that. `+1` makes it skip over the `-` as well.

Comment: I still got `0888-PMA516998-2200000M` not `PMA516998-2200000M` with this query

Comment: Nvm, you got it right but in `LOCATE` should be `LOCATE('-', ItemCode)`. Thanks a lot, man.